# Background skin and fixed layout in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Please dont send me to the hang-tree for this and thanks for reading

- This would be more a theoretical question. I've programmed a few
  years winforms lately someone asked me to make a custom design for a
  software.
- After trying to draw it in winforms i saw that it can be very
  complicated.
- Thats been said since i was looking for more simple way to work i
  draw a picture of the layout and applied it as background image on my
  form.    Of course i started to have repainting performance issues
  since the app has a size of 1800x990. So i checked and applied the
  double buffering option but the performance is still a problem because i have a lot of controls.

  So i said it might be a good time to start learning WPF . From what i understand in WPF is better to allow auto-scale and self positioning of the controls using layout tools (grids, stacks ...).
  My app would have a fixed size (no resize) so i want to just to add the background which already contains the spaces for buttons and after that just add controls over it.

My question is : in terms of working with wpf is it wrong or not?
If its not ok what would be the other aproach?

Thanks in advance,

Background
[image: Background]

With controls placed

[image: Buttons attached]

Answer (score 1):

Yes WPF has much better layout controls that you can set to have fixed sizes, ratio scaling with or without min and max sizes. For example your top 5 boxes could be expressed like this to give a grid with 5 equal sized columns that resize along with the screen

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

You can nest grids within grids and other layout controls such as stack/wrap panels. Your layout would seem to be divided up into a root grid with 3 rows. The top row being another grid with 6 columns and 2 rows. The middle row is a simple grid with 1 column and row and the bottom row is a grid with 4 columns.

Hope that helps